# How do I restore a browser session in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser

If I shut down my browser/laptop properly, then open up the browser again, it doesn't ask to restore the session. I can't add bookmarks to every link I browsed.

Is there a way that browser can ask whether you want to resume/restore the previous session the next time you launch it?

I am using Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.  Type `about:config` in the browser address bar, and accept the warning.  Look for `browser.showQuitWarnig` and set it to true.

[image]

Once you do that, every time to close the browser, you will get a box that asks if you would like to save your sessions before you quit.  You just answer yes, and the next time you open the browser, you will get back to the previous sessions.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are referring to Firefox. You can simply click History in the toolbar then Restore Previous session, or to make this permanent, go to Edit->Preferences (Or tools->options, I am not sure about your version), and under General, select to "Show my windows and tabs from last time".

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, this restores my tabs from previous session.

Answer (score 0):

There are firefox addons for it, this one looks good  https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/2324/addon-2324-latest.xpi?src=search

It can autostore previously unsaved session